# Dynamically compose the name of function to call on php

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I have csv like this.

```
id,startScore,endScore,total
1,12,34,46
2,10,20,30
.
.
```

Now I have Entity with the same column name.

So,it has the functions like these below.

`setStartScore()`
`setEndScore()`
`setTotal()`

For now my php code is like this below

```
$lines = explode('\n',$csvFile); // get CSV Content
$header = array_shift($lines); // get header
$headers = explode(",",$header)

foreach($lines as $line){ // each csv line

    $table = new Table();  
    foreach(explodes(',',$line) as $l){
        $i = 0;
        foreach($headers as $h){
            $table->set{$headers[$i]}($l[$i]) //how can I make dynamically make set***() function.
            $i++;
         }
```

I guess if I get doctrine setter/getter naming regulation, it works well though....

Comment: May I ask why you are not using **fgetcsv()** ? [link]http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: I did'nt know about fgetcsv(), it also helps my coding. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a constructor to set the data.

```
Class Table

// ..

public function __construct($id, $startScore, $endScore, $total){
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->startScore = $startScore;
    $this->endScore = $endScore;
    $this->total = $total;
}
```

Then you can create the objects like:

```
foreach($lines as $line){ // each csv line
    $data = explodes(',',$line);
    $table = new Table($data[0], $data[1], $data[2], $data[3]);
    $em->persist($table);
}

// ..flush
```

Comment: I see . Thanks to your suggestion. I use this method. It simplify the main script.